# ¿Crear campo calculado con números de forma CASE en Google Data Studio?

Tags: report

Tengo un campo numérico con notas de estudiantes de 1,0 a 7,0 llamado "nota".

¿Se puede hacer un campo calculado de forma CASE en Google Data Studio donde me especifique la equivalencia cualitativa?.

Por ejemplo:

```
de 1,0 a 4,99 = "Bajo"; 
de 4,5 a 4,99 = "Básico"; 
de 5,0 a 6,49 = "Alto"; 
de 6,5 a 7,0 = "Superior";
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esto el campo que definas como "Calificación" debería arrojar los valores que buscas,

```
CASE
WHEN nota >= 6.5 THEN "Superior"
WHEN nota >= 5 THEN "Alto"
WHEN nota >= 4.5 THEN "Básico"
WHEN nota >= 1 THEN "Bajo"
END
```

Espero sea de ayuda!

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias César.